# How do I redirect stdout in python to a function?

Tags: python, stdout

I know I can redirect stdout to a file with:

```
stdout = open("file", "a")
```

but how do I send it to a python function instead. I am working with a headless server where I would like to redirect the output to an easily monitored external source.

I would like to do:

```
def my_print_handler():
   # do something useful with the output other than printing it to a screen nobody sees

stdout = my_print_handler()

print ("Hello World") # sent to my_print_handler rather than screen
```

Comment: You don't. The function has to *read from* `sys.stdout`.